# SSRS multiple right IIF / SWITCH query

Tags: reporting-services

I want to change values to display in a report based on the right 3 characters of the column name..

```
=SWITCH (Right(Fields!Column_Name.Value,3) = "Pred", "Green",
(Right(Fields!Column_Name.Value,3) = "Lvl", "Blue")
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. Where are you putting this expression and what is the issue you are facing

Comment: "Pred" is 4 characters.